# Adding multiple roles to CakePHP Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using this tutorial to add an Authentication and  Authorization component to my app.

The problem is that all the tutorials I find only assume that a user will only have one role.  In the attached video, the roles is simply an enum field in the users table.  What I have is three tables:

1. The Users table
2. Roles Table
3. Responsibilities Table
4. A table to link Roles and Responsibilities
5. A table to link Users and Roles

I have the log in process working, up to getting the roles for the logged in user.  What is the best method to do this?  Does anyone know of a tutorial that includes this as well?  I am using Cake 2.5.2

I can post what ever code you might think relevant, but I have pretty much whats in the video.  Also, a lot of the inner working of the code seems to be hidden.  Any suggestions would be great!

thanks

**EDIT**

Below are the models for my User/Roles/Responsibilities tables that I would like added to the users object:

```
**User Table:**

id (pk)
first_name
last_name
username
password

**Role Table**

id(pk)
role_name

**Responsibility Table**

id(pk)
responsibility_name

**user_roles_membership**

id(pk)
role_id(fk)
user_id(fk)

**roles_responsibilities_membership**

id(pk)
roles_id(fk)
responsibility_id(fk)
```

[Simple Cake Authentication and Authorization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/) helps for the multi role part, at least. Responsibilities can maybe be handled separately using controller or component.

Answer (score 1):

To answer that in detail would require me to write the whole code or an exhaustive article for you - I'm not going to do that. Instead I'll point you in the right direction.

When the user is logged in, fetch all associated roles and responsibilities for that user. The following code is taken [from this part](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) of the documentation (read the whole page!). I have no clue how your data is associated so I'm just guessing here.

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Responsibility',
            'Role'
        )
    ),
    'Form'
);
```

Look at your session after the user is logged in now, you should see the additional data there. Use DebugKit for that for example or debug() the session.

Next thing is to write a customized Authorization handler that will work with that data. The documentation shows you how to do that [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects).

```
App::uses('BaseAuthorize', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class MyAuthorize extends BaseAuthorize {
    public function authorize($user, CakeRequest $request) {
        // Do things for your permission system here.
    }
}
```

Inside the authorize() method add whatever logic you need to check the permissions for your current logged in user, passed as first arg, and check them against whatever you want to check in the request, passed as 2nd arg.

All of  this is pretty straight forward and well documented [on this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html). Again, I recommend you to read the *whole* page. It should become obvious to you then how to get this done.

Also you might want to ask a more specific question than this very generic one in the case you encounter problems with the implementation.

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner.  Thank you for your response.  I believe I have read what you suggested but I am still having issues including the Roles/Responsibilities values to the user session object.  When I debug, I can see  "Responsibility" and "Role" in the This->Controller->Auth->authenticate->all->contain object but not of the actually associated values. Should the code you provided actually pull this data from the db and insert it into the session?